# Printing the URL of an OSC website

Tags: php, oscommerce

My google-fu is weak today... I'm looking for a way to dynamically print the url of an OSC site in some of the header/footer and sidebar files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo (($request_type == 'SSL') ? HTTPS_SERVER : HTTP_SERVER) . DIR_WS_CATALOG; ?>
```

Comment: If that's the solution you're happy with, hit that checkmark next to this answer